# Nested callback function not working properly swift

Tags: swift, completionhandler

I am trying to implement nested completion handlers but for some reason, my second handler is not firing upon completion. This is how the code looks like

```
//User presses a button on a cell. Code is in `cellForRowAtIndex...`
 cell.callback = {
            print("in CFRAIP")
            self.showPopUpDialog(completionHandler: { () -> Void in 
                print("AfterPOPUPDIALOG")
                self.requestBookingWithCompletionHandler(fetchBookingForDate: self.currentDate, row: indexPath.row)
            })
        }


func showPopUpDialog(completionHandler: () -> Void ){

    print("In show PopUPdialog")

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Uppgifter", message: "Skriv in namn och telefonnummer", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Boka", style: .default) { (_) in

        //getting the input values from user
        self.bokadNamn = (alertController.textFields?[0].text)!
        self.bokadTelefon = (alertController.textFields?[1].text)!

        print("pressed ok in popup")
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Avbryt", style: .cancel) { (_) in}

    //adding textfields to our dialog box
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "Namn"
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    }
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "Telefonnummer"
    }

    alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    //finally presenting the dialog box
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is the prints that I am getting:

```
in CFRAIP
In show PopUPdialog
pressed ok in popup
```

`print("AfterPOPUPDIALOG")` is not being fired and my network request is not being run after the user pressed ok in the `PopUP`. I feel like it is something really simple that I am missing but unfortunately, I am to blind to see it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the function `func showPopUpDialog(completionHandler: () -> Void ) {`, you are not calling the completion handler `completionHandler` anywhere.

If you will not call your completion handler, how will print statement `print("AfterPOPUPDIALOG")` be executed?

Call your completion handler `completionHandler` at the appropriate place.

Comment: Wow.. Haha i am really too tired. Thank you